# How to find total amount of columns with a specific word in a dataframe - R

Tags: r, dataframe

so I am trying to find the number of samples that are labelled with the phrase 'PaperB' in a very larger data frame in R, I have used the following:

`df[grep("PaperB", names(df))]`

but this has given me all the columns labelled with Tissue B and their values, rather than  the total amount of PaperB samples, how could i change this to just get the total amount?

thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

**strong text**If I understood you correctly:
Here is `dplyr` solution using the `iris` dataset:
Here we count the columns that contain the string "Sepal" in their name with `length()` function:

```
library(dplyr)
iris %>% 
  select(contains("Sepal")) %>% 
  length()
```

```
[1] 2
```

**BASE R
For you code we would do:**

```
length(iris[grep("Sepal", names(iris))])
```

Comment: could you explain what '%>%' means? As I think I understand your answer but I'm not sure what the function of '%>%' is

Comment: `%>%` is the pipe operator from `magrittr` package. In base R the equivalent is `|>`. I strongly recommend to study base R functions along with `tidyverse` functions. Please see also the second part of the answer, which is base R.

Answer (score 0):

As the data frame is large I would avoid pulling its data and deal only with metadata. You were very close:

```
cn <- colnames(iris) 
gr <- grep("PaperB", cn)
length(gr)
```

Or in a pipeline:

```
cn <- colnames(iris) 
grep("PaperB", cn) |>
  length()
```